# jQuery Tooltip - How do you close the tooltip when a user starts typing in the textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I have a tooltip associated with some textboxes as follows:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: "[data-my-latitude]",
    position: {
        my: "center bottom-15",
        at: "center top",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
            $( this ).css( position );
            $( "" )
                .addClass( "arrow" )
                .addClass( feedback.vertical )
                .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
                .appendTo( this );
        }
    },
    content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( "[data-my-latitude]" ) ) {

            if (element.prop('disabled'))
                return null;

            return _map.build(element.val());
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Everything works fine, but I will like to close the close the tooltip window if the user types a different value into the textbox.

Comment: Do you know how to close the tooltip in an event handler?  If so, I think you just keep to handle the keypress event on the textbox.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon I added events option but it doesn't work. <code> events: {
                    input: 'click, blur, keydown, keypress',
                    checkbox: 'mouseover click, mouseout',
                }</code>

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I ended up doing this:

```
element.keyup( function () {
    $(".ui-tooltip-content").parents('div').remove();
});
```